# Unknown CMake command "tablegen"

Tags: cmake, llvm

I'm trying to compile MLIR with the command:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=“mlir” ../mlir
```

Then came the CMake Error:

```
...

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (tablegen):
  Unknown CMake command "tablegen".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  include/mlir/Analysis/CMakeLists.txt:2 (mlir_tablegen)

...
```

I can't figure out what went wrong, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Whichever llvm project you want to build, you still need to run `cmake` for the source directory corresponding to **top-level** llvm directory, not for its *subdirectory*.

**Top-level** directory is where you clone the project https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

I solve the problem by run `cmake` for the source directory.

It can work with the guide of [MLIR Getting Started](https://mlir.llvm.org/getting_started/).